# Xamarin iOS: unable save PKCS12 data in the iOS keychain

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**Use case:**

The app imports PKCS 12 file (with cert and private key) and saves it for later use.

**Current status:**

I was able to use SecImportExport.ImportPkcs12 in order to get SecIdentity and SecTrust objects. 
Unfortunately I’m unable to assign SecIdentity and SecTrust object to SecRecord.

**The code:**

```
SecIdentity identityObject = ...;
SecTrust trustObject = ...;

SecRecord record = new SecRecord(SecKind.Identity);
record.Account = "Identity";
record.ValueData = ?   //HOW TO CONVERT SecIdentity to NSData?

var res = SecKeyChain.Add(record);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing a .p12 certificate in keychain to use later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598729/storing-a-p12-certificate-in-keychain-to-use-later)

Comment: @Krumelur:  the question is about the native iOS application, not the Xamarin app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SecRecord.SetValueRef (identityObject)` which can be used to store keys (`SecKey`), certificates (`SecCertificate`) or identities.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended usage. Unfortunately there is a bug in Xamarin iOS, which causes troubles with retrieving the identity later. Here is a link to bugtracker:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24972